# Django: how to write models.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In application i have Post model. In admin panel i want to have only one entry - "Posts" with one link to add Post. In list of Posts in admin i want to see all of them.

All posts have it's title, content and other basic fields.

***But:***

Due to Post Source, posts may have different fields.

```
Sources:

--- First
--- Second
--- Third
--- ......
```

For example, Post with first Source ***must*** have Poll (but has no category). Post with second Source ***must*** belong to category in Category branch #1 (but has no Poll). Post with third source may have Image field (but no category and no poll) and so on.

```
Category branch #1

--- cb1_first
--- cb1_second
--- cb1_third

Category branch #....

--- cb2_first
--- cb2_second
--- cb2_third
```

So, in Post add-page i want to write title, content, other basic things, than i select Source and due to choice other fields appears (for first source it is Poll, for second - list of categories in Category branch #1 and so on).

If i make base class Post, and then extend it with other classes, i'll get extra tables in SQL and many items in application admin (i.e. add Basic Post, add Video Post, add Post with poll, add Post with category branch #2...)

Asking for advice, how to organize such application.

Comment: Maybe have a look at how [Django's UserAdmin](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/admin.py) does it -- they have more than one step when you create a user.

Comment: I have only one admin user, and it's only example. Real models have no assotiations with User model...

Comment: I know, I'm just saying the admin site creates users in more than one step (username/password, then the other stuff); if you figured out how they did that, you could have one step where you choose the source, then the next step would be determined based on what source was chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a reason why I'm a strong opponent to doing validation at the database level with things like null=False. Make a single `Post` model with all the fields that any type of post can have, but don't enforce the requirements on the model (`blank=True, null=True`).

Then, instead, validate that one field or another is required, etc. on your forms, specifically ModelForms when dealing with the Admin.

If a certain field is required in one instance, you can enforce that using:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.instance.source == 'first':
            self.fields['poll'].required = True
```

Then, for showing only the actual fields that should be shown based on the source, you can either work up a bit of JavaScript for that, or you can actually explicitly exclude them from the admin with `ModelAdmin.get_fieldsets()`. Basically the process is thus:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    fieldsets = (
        (None, { 'fields': ('common_field_1', 'common_field_2', 'common_field_3',),
    )
    poll_fieldsets = (
        (None, { 'fields': ('common_field_1', 'common_field_2', 'common_field_3', 'poll',),
    )

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj and obj.source == 'first':
            return self.poll_fieldsets
        else:
            return super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request=request, obj=obj)
```

Comment: problem 1:- This leaves so many blank fields in each row of the `Post` model table. problem 2:- It'd be hard to extend if you don't know all the fields required by the `Post` model in advance.

Comment: chrisdpratt, answer looks good! But I'm embarrassed about blank fields in database. If i have no choice, i'll certanly go that way! But may be there is another opportunity to organize such application? I found something about "generic relations", in comments above there is something about "add item in two step" as we usually add users through admin

Comment: Generic relations are a completely different beast. Using your post example, let's say you actually ended up created different models for each PollPost, CategoryPost, etc. On your Blog model, you couldn't simply reference Post, you'd instead of to make a foreign key to each post type. That's where generic relations come in. They let you have one foreign key, that can hold whatever kind of model, indiscriminately. But while their use is sometimes the best and only way to accomplish something, I've found that they are an enormous headache and very rarely actually the best solution to a problem.

Comment: As far a blank DB fields go, who cares? It's just a repository for data. I'll take a messy database and clean code versus the reverse any day.

Answer (score 0):

First create a model with whatever the basic fields you require for a post(say `Post` model). Then you can create a model for sources - `Source` model. `Post` model should have a foreign key representing the source with which it was created. The `Source` model should contain a field to store the name of a model to instantiate in order to store additional fields of the posts with the given source. Then create the all the models for each additional field sets you require, Each should have a foreign key field with the `Post` model. For example you can create a `Poll` model with a foreign key to `Post`.

After modeling the data like this you can just refer to `Source` model to resolve all the field types when creating posts as well as retrieving them.